# Invalid Hook Call use-neo4j

Tags: javascript, reactjs, neo4j, react-hooks

I recently started building a react app.
I wanted to configure a neo4j database attached to the application. I decided to use the `use-neo4j` hook. I followed the basic step of creating the driver instance like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./css/index.css";
import App from "./js/App";
import Nav from "./js/Nav";
import { Neo4jProvider, createDriver } from "use-neo4j";

const driver = createDriver("neo4j", "localhost", 7687, "lode", "neo4j");

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Neo4jProvider driver={driver}>
      <Nav />
      <App />
    </Neo4jProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

But I ended up having the Invalid Hook Call error.
Except if I remove the `Neo4jProvider` tags
Seen in this image here [image]

I tried everything I can to fix it, I'm pretty new at React.
I would love someone to help me if they can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the error says, you can only call hooks inside the body of a functional component.  So I would probably create a component that initiates the driver and returns the component that uses it -

```
import { Neo4jProvider, createDriver } from "use-neo4j";

const NeoProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const driver = createDriver("neo4j", "localhost", 7687, "lode", "neo4j");

  return (
    <Neo4jProvider driver={driver}>
      {children}
    </Neo4jProvider>
  );
}
```

And then import that at your top level and use that instead of the `Neo4jProvider` you're importing from the package.

Comment: This gives the same result I'm afraid.

Comment: I honestly think it;s the multiple react issue, but don't know how to fix that one

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue, I had multiple Reactjs running